# Изменение сочетания клавиш Ctrl+Enter

Tags: jquery, javascript

Делаю что-то наподобие отправки сообщений сайта ВКонтакте.
В редактируемом поле:

```
<div class="text-td" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

при нажатии Enter происходит перенос на другую строку. А если нажать Ctrl+Enter, это вызовет  нажатие на блок

```
<div class="ok-td"></div>
```

Вот код:

```
$("body").on("keypress", ".text-td", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      $(this).parent().find(".ok-td").click();
      e.preventDefault();      
   } else {
       // Ничего
    }  
  }
});
```

Необходимо наоборот, при нажатии на Enter понятно, что должно произойти, но не понятно, что должно выполнится при нажатии сочетания Ctrl+Enter, ведь его нужно подменить на просто Enter:

```
 $("body").on("keypress", ".text-td", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            // тут должен быть Enter 
       } else {
          $(this).parent().find(".ok-td").click();
          e.preventDefault();   
        }  
      }
    });
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы при нажатии на enter отправляло сообщение?

Comment: да, а при нажатии Ctrl+Enter был Enter

Comment: При нажатии на Enter событии сделать не проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/wcy5qL0k/

Дело еще и в том, что при зажатом Ctrl некоторые браузеры передают не `13`, `10`.

#### UPD

Вот для `[contenteditable]`: http://jsfiddle.net/wcy5qL0k/1/ (украдено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div)).

Comment: Спасибо! А только с textarea? С ДИВом не получается?

Comment: Вот как ВКонтакте реализовано: 

    <div id="im_editable57710338" class="im_editable" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">
    один
    <div>
    два
    <br>
    <div>
    три
    <br>
    <div>
    четыре
    <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: т.е. они вставляю  <div> четыре <br> </div>, и, видимо, устанавливают фокус.

Comment: Дополнил ответ